# docker not able to connect to remote mysql database even after making the ssh tunnel via a bastion host

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, containers

I am trying to connect to a remote DB via a ssh tunnel .
I am able to utilize the tunnel and make the connection from local machine to remote DB

but I when I try run the application within a docker container , it never resolves the connection

1. made a ssh tunnel with command

`ssh -L 5555:{remote_DB_host}:3306 {bastion_host}`

2. test connection from local machine

`mysql -u{username} -h127.0.0.1 -P5555 -p`

connection successful

3. run the docker image locally

`docker run -it --rm -e "JPDA_ADDRESS=*:8000" -e "JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket" -p 5033:8000 {aws_docker_image_arn_from_ECS}`

4.Application fails to make connection to database

I am connected to a VPN which gives me access to bastion host by LDAP user but the container running locally seems to be out of the VPN network .
this might not be the real prob .

Comment: IIUC you need to access the DB through your localhost's port `5555`. I don't see this configuration reflected in your `docker run ...` but you may wish to try `--net=host` to flatten the host's network into the container, if the container is indeed looking for the host's `5555`.

Comment: --net=host already tried , same issue
what other config do you expect to see here ?

Comment: That's curious but perhaps explained by.... where are you configuring the database connection? With `mysql` you correctly pointed it at `-P5555` where is the equivalent for the `aws_docker_image_arn_from_ECS` image?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here ,there is a class with mysql connection string , with given hostname and port . and the ECS image contains this code .what else do you expect here

Comment: You've explained it. The container's connection to the database is not shown. You demonstrate being able to access the database from the host (`mysql ...`) but you don't show how the container connects to the database. The container's connection string needs to be `[host]:5555` and, if you use `docker run ... --net=host`, the container's connection string could be `localhost:5555`. If you don't, the container needs to be able to resolve the host's address.